# django unicode error on admin page

Tags: django, unicode, django-admin

I'm vaguely familiar with the nature of unicode, but I'm not sure how all the pieces fit together.  I have an error when displaying specific instances in the admin page.

> Caught UnicodeEncodeError while
>   rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character u'\u2019' in position 29:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

Here's my model:

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    xml = models.TextField(max_length=1000000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str('Proposal for: %s' % self.project.name)
```

I've gone into my mysql database and verified that the DB, table, and column are all collated as utf8_unicode_ci, so I don't understand why the page is trying to render as ascii.  Looking at various forums and docs, I see mention of the **str** and **unicode** functions, but they don't seem to have anything to do with this as the list of instances shows up fine in on the admin page.  It's just showing the actual instance form that causes a problem.

Here's some example xml I pulled from phpmyadmin...

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proposal>

  <section title="OVERVIEW">
    <section title="Introduction">
      <text>
    This proposal is not in the system because it was completed as an agreement in Word previous to us getting this application up and running.  Please refer to the attachments in this project for documentation or to see the agreement.
      </text>
    </section>
  </section>
</proposal>
```

I've even tried to deliberately exclude the xml (which I can't do in the long run since I'd like it to be editable in the admin section), but I still get the same error, so I'm not even convinced the xml is even the problem.  If the xml isn't the problem, I have no idea what else could be keeping this page from being displayed.

```
class ProposalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('xml',)
admin.site.register(Project)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's a `’` character somewhere, probably in `self.project.name`. You could probably find it if you check the whole error message.

However, if you're getting unicode results from your database it would probably be smarter to do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ('Proposal for: %s' % self.project.name).encode('ascii', errors='replace')
```

The *smartest* thing to do, since it's [recommended by the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode), is to implement the `__unicode__` function instead:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Proposal for: %s' % self.project.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the encode() trick - ps: it should be `encode('ascii','replace')`

Comment: @Yuji Tomita, I think you can call it both ways. Keyword arguments and stuff: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Comment: Those docs say nothing about keyword arguments. Here's what I get in 2.6: `TypeError: encode() takes no keyword arguments`. Docs say in 2.7, support for keyword arguments was added. Hopefully I can be done with 2.6 ASAP but it's still massively used.

Comment: Yes you're completely right. My bad! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: when i add u return it says ,,,, global name 'u' is not defined

Comment: `u return`? It should be like in the answer above.

Answer (score 8):

2019 is [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf), commonly used as a curly apostrophe.

The problem probably *is* caused by you using `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`, and [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#other-model-instance-methods) recommends that you only use `__unicode__`.

The list of instances probably shows up fine because it doesn't include the field that contains the apostrophe.

Comment: upvote a billion times for the `__unicode__` recommendation! i spent like 3 hours looking through reasons why i was getting errors in the admin detail view. the __unicode__ override fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

(I'd add this as a comment to Andre's but don't have the 50 points yet)

This:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Proposal for: %s' % self.project.name
```

Should be

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Proposal for: %s' % self.project.name
```

This is especially true if you are using a variable in the definition that references another model that may return a string with characters unicode doesn't like.  Putting in the "u" in front of the text returned makes sure everything is kosher and returned as unicode.