# Unicode error in django admin

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode

I'm getting this error when trying to view objects with names not in english in the django admin console.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My .py file's header is

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This is the code

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

I've looked around for other topics on the subject and found the folowing solutions : 
I've tried changing the encoding in the py file to unicode , i've tried writing `__str__` as `unicode(self.name)` and as `u'%s',self.name`. I also tried adding a `__unicode__` member with the same combinations. Didn't Work. I've also tried syncing the db again and bouncing the server. Nothing.

The weird thing is that the names are displayed in the menus but when i'm trying to edit the object i'm getting the error.

I would appreciate any help.

Python 2.7, Django 1.5.2, Ubuntu 12 , Postgres.

a Full trace back of the exception

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/calc/owner/3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 284, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 284, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 606, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 41, in _dec
    args[0] = force_text(args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 107, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `__str__` to `__unicode__`?

Comment: added the python3 tag since it is most likely relevant here

Comment: @ThiefMaster: surprising that the OP claims this is Python 3, the default ASCII codec implies that this is Python 2 instead.

Comment: Please give us the **full** traceback of the exception.

Comment: @kroolik - Yes I tried that.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters - you'r right, I got mistaken. its 2.7.

Comment: I am very surprised you are using `__str__()` on a Django model; always use [`__unicode__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__) instead. I suspect something else is wrong here, but you do want to avoid using `__str__()` as it should return a *byte string*, but `self.name` is always Unicode instead.

Comment: you know what, it works. I'm new to this. Thanks man.

Answer (score 12):

Change your code like this :

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

See this link : [django unicode error on admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560226/django-unicode-error-on-admin-page)